# How to blur the UI Screen without using any external library?

Tags: java, android, android-library, blur

I am using Socket connection for performing my tasks. When socket gets disconnected I want UI to be blurred out and a button to be shown which will try reconnecting when clicked. Rest are taken care of, I just want to know whether there is any way to blur the UI(portion above the button of course) without using any external library.
I have gone through this link : https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView , but I don't want to use it.

I haven't tried any ways yet.

Comment: Do you mean you will show a popup and blur the background behind or simply blur the background?

Comment: try to use alpha to the parent view of your layout

Comment: `I haven't tried any ways yet.` so you came to ask here without any research done? The 'Help Center' from StackOverflow disallows this. See `Search, and research`: "...and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The library you linked uses renderscript. You too can use renderscript to do your blurring job.

Comment: @Zun haven't tried anyways doesn't mean haven't researched . There are plenty of libraries that allow doing that particular task but I dont want to use any external library as i am using it for my SDK. So Can you come up with a solution instead ? Thanks.

Comment: @sanjeev Hi, I need to blur the complete view and not the background itsel

Comment: @AshutoshChatterjee provide the code where you need to blur. I shall help you out..

Answer (score 3):

You can use renderscript to produce blurs. You first need to get the screenshot of the view you want to blur.

```
public Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
   View screenView = view.getRootView();
   screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
   screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
   return bitmap;
}
```

Then you can pass that bitmap to your renderscript

```
private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.4f;

//Set the radius of the Blur. Supported range 0 < radius <= 25
private static float BLUR_RADIUS = 10.5f;

public Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image, float blurRadius) {

    Bitmap outputBitmap = null;

    if (image != null) {

        if (blurRadius == 0) {
            return image;
        }

        if (blurRadius < 1) {
            blurRadius = 1;
        }

        if (blurRadius > 25) {
            blurRadius = 25;
        }

        BLUR_RADIUS = blurRadius;

        int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
        int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

        Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
        outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
    }

    return outputBitmap;
}
```

and then use this bitmap as the background for the view with your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a view with blur/half-transparent background and with a button. When your socket get disconnected, set the visibility of the View to **Visible**; when it is connected/reconnected, simply set the visibility back to **Gone**. This way you can block users from interacting with the UI when the socket is disconnected.

You can also use `setAlpha()` to set the "blurriness" of the background.

Comment: blur and opacity change is arguably not the same thing.

Comment: True... but that's my workaround =D Hey, saw your comments up there mentioning RenderScript, I think it is good, can you answer the question so I can upvote?

Comment: I added the renderscript solution as an answer.